# html5 Liquid CSS’ fixed left main content area with right content liquid

Tags: html, css, templates, layout

I am having problem making the my template a liquid layout but just having the main content area (left area) fixed at 990px can anyone help with this area of using liquid and fixed please?

layout is like so;

```
              central 

              banner
```

main content left/fixed right column with image central
footer

Many thanks guys!

Comment: Yeah can you post an example?

I think this might work for your content area:

Answer (score 0):

An example or live link would be nice. But if your simply trying to have a content area have a set width of 990px but then be responsive when the window is smaller then that this should work:

HTML example:

```
<div class="content">
<p>Content in here</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
display: block;
max-width: 990px;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, i have a mock up example, but it wont let me upload image template.

Comment: Hi matt ive added it to a link, thanks matt http://pfpaccesssolutions.com/sam_scott_test/task-page-sam-scott.html